# How can we export dict containg list as value in csv file

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose this is input format...

```
    {'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
     Flag:['True'],
     City:'',

}
```

and i want to export this data as follow in csv file in python

```
ID   Name  Flag  City
1      A   True   ''
2      B          ''
3      c     
4      D
5      E
```

and so on...How can we do it ..? Thankx in advance
PF:Im getting input formate from django models

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
columns = list(dict.keys())

try:
    with open(output_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you would have to make sure that all lists in the dictionary's values have the same length. Any other situation would be bad practice.

Suppose that it is the case, e.g.

```
d = {'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
 'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
 'Flag':[True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 'City':['']*7,
}
```

Now you can build a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

and convert it to CSV

```
df.to_csv('/tmp/test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not strictly looking for a csv like you've mentioned, and are ok with having `NaN`s in it, try using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "Name": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
    "Flag": ["True"],
    "City": "",
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k, v in d.items()]))

df.to_csv("1.csv",index=False)
```

This fills the unavailable elements with `NaN`.

Output:

```
   ID Name  Flag City
0   1    A  True     
1   2    B   NaN  NaN
2   3    C   NaN  NaN
3   4    D   NaN  NaN
4   5    E   NaN  NaN
5   6    F   NaN  NaN
6   7    G   NaN  NaN
7   8  NaN   NaN  NaN
8   9  NaN   NaN  NaN
9  10  NaN   NaN  NaN
```